# Method callable from multiple objects

Tags: java, android

I have an application interface divided into fragments. I would like to create a method that can be called from different kinds of objects (let say a View or a KeyEvent), without using listeners: I don't want to create programmatically the elements into layout.

So, if I were working only with View elements, I shall create a method like this

```
public void myMethod(View view) {
   switch(view.getId()) {
   ...
   }
}
```

and link all the elements by using `onClick` item into .xml file. It works like a charm.

Is there a way I can call my method also with other types of objects? In a certain situation I need to call that method via KeyEvent, so I tried this way:

```
public void myMethod(Object caller) {
   if(caller instanceof View) {
      //button pressed
      ...
   } else if (caller instanceof KeyEvent) {
      //key pressed
      ...
   }
}
```

It doesn't work, I get an exception at runtime if I press a button: it wants a method with the signature `myMethod(View view)`.
Any solution?

Comment: Post full error stacktrace. That may give some clues.

Comment: `07-10 16:38:07.859: E/AndroidRuntime(331): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method launchSearch(View) in the activity class com.tinybox.androclickclient.Home for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'stop_search_button'
`

Comment: My method has signature `launchSearch(Object)`.

Comment: I think your launchSerach is inside anonymous class (inside of onClick logic) which is not visible for other cases.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using two methods, one for views one for keyevents and if you want to bundle the handling into ONE method, just call that third method by the previous methods.